# Microsoft Word BI Publisher: how to hide table header row at first occurrence

Tags: oracle, ms-word, rtf, bi-publisher

Currently I am working on Oracle report using BI publisher desktop extension for MS Word.
In RTF layout I have a requirement to build receipts table and dynamically loop through receipts XML data. In oversimplified way it looks like that:

```
`<G_RECEIPTS>
<RECEIPT_DATE>2022-05-12</RECEIPT_DATE><RECEIPT_AMOUNT>10</RECEIPT_AMOUNT>
</G_RECEIPTS>
<G_RECEIPTS>
<RECEIPT_DATE>2022-05-26</RECEIPT_DATE><RECEIPT_AMOUNT>5</RECEIPT_AMOUNT>
</G_RECEIPTS>
<G_RECEIPTS>
<RECEIPT_DATE>2022-05-11</RECEIPT_DATE><RECEIPT_AMOUNT>5</RECEIPT_AMOUNT>
</G_RECEIPTS>`
```

[image]

And preview output looks ok

[image]

But according to the requirements, table header row (item, quantity and so on) should not be visible on first appearance, only after page break. Based on this example: header row must be hidden after "Content" word, but visible on page 2

Originally I tried to capture "current page" system variable, but according to the official oracle forums, it is technically not possible.

Comment: No idea, sorry. But, are you sure you got it right? You said "table header row should not be visible on first appearance, only after page break" - that doesn't make sense to me. So *they* (those who required it) want to see a table with no heading and wonder what these values represent, and then - after turning the paper and seeing the rest of the report - finally notice the heading. That's ... wrong, from my point of view.

Comment: @Littlefoot Yes exactly, from UI perspective it is completely dumb and makes no sense. But it is what it is.

Comment: @Littlefoot imagine not enough rows for the table to span multiple pages. :s

Answer (score 0):

You can use xdoxslt:set_variable, and if:xdoxslt:get_variable. Set it to 0 before the table, for the header row, repeat on all pages, use an if condition checking if variable is >0 for the whole row. Then set the variable to 1 each data row. I have not tested it, but that's where I'd start.

Some example syntax:

```
<?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, 'variable name', value)?>

<?xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX, 'variable name')?>

<?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, 'x', xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX, 'variable name' + 1)?>
```

Agreed with the other commenters, this is a strange requirement. I'd push back and ask for rationalization why the requirement exists.